# How to do a true reverse of a String in Java, including code points outside the BMP?

Tags: java, unicode

One of the primary goals of Java was to represent each and every glyph in any language using a basic primitive type; when Java was born, there was Unicode, and at this time Unicode defined glyphs by numbers, all of which were less than or equal to 65535.

Hence `char` was born in Java: an unsigned, 16bit integer.

However, things have changed in the Unicode world. There now exist numerous glyphs whose number is greater than 65535.

While Java has acknowledged this and represents such code points using surrogate pairs (essentially, a `char` is now a UTF-16 code unit), the standard JDK does not provide a method to reverse a string code point wise (`StringBuilder#reverse`, for instance, only cares about individual chars).

Assuming Java 8, how would you code a method which does true string reversing, that is, taking code points outside the BMP into account?

Comment: There's also this thing called combining characters. Reversing the code points in `"Québec"` results in `"ceb́euQ"`. That's because the combining acute accent appears above the *preceding* letter. The assumption that one code point corresponds to one character is wrong.

Comment: @roeland it depends on the canonical decomposition of the string (`é` has its own code point, but it can be decomposed into "e, acute accent"); but yes, the solution below does not account for that... Java does have the API to change the decomposition, but I can't recall it at the moment. And for that matter, I have _never_ encountered a decomposition of `é` like that...

Comment: @roeland The question asks about reversing code points, not characters. Neither is correct or incorrect; it all depends on your requirements.

Comment: @fge fair enough, that was just an example. A common example these days on the internet are emoji, a lot of them consist of multiple code points.

Comment: @roeland emojis are single code points! Or there is also decomposition for emojis, which I have never heard of...

Comment: @fge no: see for instance http://emojipedia.org/flags/ and http://emojipedia.org/family-man-woman-girl-boy/

Comment: @roeland ah, I didn't know about that... Thanks for the links!

Comment: @roeland: Just wonder if Java provides APIs to determine if a codepoint is combining or not?

Comment: @AdrianShum I don't know. The technical term for these groups of code points is "grapheme clusters". As soon as you have to do things like case conversion, comparing, sorting or splitting, I'd look for a library to handle all the subtleties arising from various scripts.

Comment: @roeland Thanks so much for the keyword! :D Found some information and I will update my answer to (hopefully) handle grapheme clusters correctly.

Answer (score 6):

One such method is as follows:

```
public static String trueReverse(final String input)
{
    final Deque<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    input.codePoints().forEach(queue::addFirst);

    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    queue.forEach(sb::appendCodePoint);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Not optimized, but fully functional. Try with this, for instance:

```
public final class Test
{
    public static String trueReverse(final String input)
    {
        final Deque<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        input.codePoints().forEach(queue::addFirst);

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        queue.forEach(sb::appendCodePoint);

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final String input = "abc\ud83d\udca9de";

        System.out.println(trueReverse(input));
    }
}
```

Yes, this happens to use [a defined character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4a9/index.htm)... Now, your font may, or may not, display that character correctly.

Note how this Unicode character is coded in the Java string literal: `\ud83d\udca9`.

Answer (score 1):

This solution avoids boxing by using an `int` array:

```
public static String reverse(String input) {
    int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray();
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, codePoints.length)
            .map(i -> codePoints.length - i)
            .map(i -> codePoints[i])
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @roeland by providing the keywords for the concept which helped me to find related information at http://developers.linecorp.com/blog/?p=3473.  Here is an implementation that (supposedly) handles grapheme clusters.

```
static String reverseGraphemeCluster(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BreakIterator it = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance();
    it.setText(s);

    int end = it.last();
    for (int start = it.previous();
        start != BreakIterator.DONE;
        end = start, start=it.previous()) {

        sb.append(s, start,end);
    }
    return sb.toString();

}
```

For example, `reverseGraphemeCluster("abcde\ud83d\udca9\ud83c\udd71\ufe0f")` gives `"\ud83c\udd71\ufe0f\ud83d\udca9ecbda"`

(`\ud83c\udd71\ufe0f` is one grapheme clusters. `\ud83d\udca9` is a codepoint outside of BMP)

Again, no boxing/unboxing, nor intermediate int array.

---

If you want to just reverse codepoints, irrespectivie of grapheme clusters, here is a solution that is easier to read, and require less space as there is neither boxing/unboxing of Integer, nor temporary intermediate `int[]`

```
String reverse(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = s.length(), p=i; i > 0; i=p) {
        p = s.offsetByCodePoints(i, -1);
        sb.appendCodePoint(s.codePointAt(p));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

Or, even forget about using codepoint-APIs by handling surrogate pair manually:

(Here we assume the string is containing correct surrogate pairs):

```
static String reverse(String s) {
    if (s == null || s.length() < 2) return s;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = s.length()-1 ; i >=0; --i) {
        if (Character.isLowSurrogate(s.charAt(i))) {
            --i;
            sb.append(s.charAt(i)).append(s.charAt(i+1));
        } else {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```